# Linux shell script to automate user creation

Tags: linux

Linux enables tasks which are regularly carried out to be automated through the use of shell scripts. How do I write a shell script that could automate the task of creating new users and assigning them to specific groups?

Comment: What problem are you having doing that exactly? We're not going to write the script for you, and there's tons of docs out there about scripting that you can learn/inspire yourself from.

Comment: You should use `adduser` for add a user and `usermod` for adding a user to a group. There should be no need of a shell script.

Comment: @Chrispie in the event you do have `adduser` available, you don't need `usermod` for adding to a group. `adduser foo bar` adds user `foo` to group `bar`.

Answer (score 4):

Although you could add a user the (very) old-fashioned way, by editing `/etc/passwd` and creating and configuring a home directory, there are already commands that automate the process for you. Use `adduser` and you won't feel the need for further automation (unless you have a ton of new users you want to add). There's also `useradd`, which is more low-level.

The `adduser` program is extensively configurable via the file `/etc/adduser.conf`.

The initial contents of the user's home directory normally come from `/etc/skel` (be sure to list it with `ls -a`, since it's all dot files).